# Why my custom.css file isn't modifying my materialize.css?

Tags: css, materialize

I wanted to modify the grid system, add some borders to rows, columns etc. I know, that I should create separate folder (in my case it's custom.css) and write it there, but it looks like my site sees this file, but doesn't see changes in there.

I tried this in my custom.css

```
.row-custom {
   border: 5px solid #42a5f5;
}
```

and just add row-custom to row class

Like this

```
  <div class="row row-custom">
  <div class="col s12 ">This div is 12-columns wide on all screen sizes</div>
  <div class="col s6 ">6-columns (one-half)</div>
  <div class="col s6">6-columns (one-half)</div>
  </div>
```

If I add .row-custom into my header in layout.html it works properly.

Here's my custom.css file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rQrO.jpg 
and here's my custom.css view in sources from the website:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnUSW.jpg 
(these css I also had to put into header because otherwise it wasn't working, I deleted it earlier)

My header:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUc1d.jpg

Also, my materialize.min.css works correctly.

I have no idea why there is no changes in sources custom.css, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see how is this related to django ? There is no tag of css.

Comment: I think Django is messing up something

Answer (score 0):

I´ve made the same code and it worked, the question is, have you imported your custom.css into the file?

if not, try to import it, or chance the place for importation, as shown in the next example, the above code should work

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Portfolio Blog</title>
    
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .row-custom {
      border: 5px solid #42a5f5;
    } 
  </style>
  
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
  <div class="row row-custom">
  <div class="col s12">This div is 12-columns wide on all screen sizes</div>
  <div class="col s6 ">6-columns (one-half)</div>
  <div class="col s6">6-columns (one-half)</div>
  </div>
  
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `!important` to the line in your css file so that you override the `materializecss.css` defaults?

```css
.row-custom {
  border: 5px solid #42a5f5 !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="row row-custom">
      <div class="col s12">This div is 12-columns wide on all screen sizes</div>
      <div class="col s6 ">6-columns (one-half)</div>
      <div class="col s6">6-columns (one-half)</div>
    </div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: I've solved the problem. I've changed the name of my 'custom.css' to 'main.css' and everything is working. Dunno why

Answer (score 0):

In materialize CSS there is a problem with overriding the CSS so use`!important` like below.

`.row-custom { border: 5px solid #42a5f5 !important; }`